# Match two dictionary keys efficiently in Python

Tags: python, hash-map

I have two dictionaries that I need the keys to match and if they match i will get the value of the first dictionary and then get the value of 2nd dictionary and build a new dictionary out of those.

```
dic1 = {u'ShutterHours': 732, u'ShieldHours': 732, u'MaskHours': 28, u'TargetHours': 790, u'GndRingHours': 25}
dic2 = {u'ShutterHours': u'Shutter Hours', u'ShieldHours': u'Shield Hours', u'MaskHours': u'Mask Hours', u'TargetHours': u'Target Hours', u'GndRingHours': u'Ground Ring Hours'}
```

This is my code so far:

```
final = {}
for k,k2 in zip(dic1,dic2):
    if k == k2:
        final[dic2[k]] = dic1[k]
```

Expected output:

```
{u'Ground Ring Hours': 25, u'Shutter Hours': 732, u'Shield Hours': 732, u'Mask Hours': 28, u'Target Hours': 790}
```

This works fine but I'm a bit skeptical if this is the best and Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: What's the expected output for this example? Are you sure that it works?

Comment: edited the question @200_success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mechanism is so fragile that I can't tell for sure what it is supposed to do.  The main issue is that you can't reliably predict the order in which the keys of a dictionary will be enumerated.  For example, this seems to work as you intend:

```
>>> dic1 = {u'ShutterHours': 732, u'ShieldHours': 732, u'MaskHours': 28, u'TargetHours': 790, u'GndRingHours': 25}
>>> dic2 = {u'ShutterHours': u'Shutter Hours', u'ShieldHours': u'Shield Hours', u'MaskHours': u'Mask Hours', u'TargetHours': u'Target Hours', u'GndRingHours': u'Ground Ring Hours'}
>>> list(zip(dic1, dic2))
[('ShutterHours', 'ShutterHours'), ('ShieldHours', 'ShieldHours'), ('GndRingHours', 'GndRingHours'), ('MaskHours', 'MaskHours'), ('TargetHours', 'TargetHours')]
```

However, if you insert one entry into `dic2`, the whole thing might fall apart:

```
>>> …
>>> dic2[''] = 'empty string'
>>> list(zip(dic1, dic2))
[('ShutterHours', 'ShutterHours'), ('ShieldHours', ''), ('GndRingHours', 'GndRingHours'), ('MaskHours', 'ShieldHours'), ('TargetHours', 'MaskHours')]
```

What you probably want is a dict comprehension.

```
final = {dic2[k]: v for k, v in dic1.items()}
```

Better variable names would make the code easier to understand as well (e.g. `labels` instead of `dic2`).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, mainly those dictionaries should  and will always have the same length. @200_success

Comment: You still can't count on them to have any predictable iteration order.

Comment: You should at least use `final = {dic2[k]: v for k, v in dic1.items() if k in dic2}` for the cases where a key is in dic1 and not in dic2.